# How to retrieve google analytics event tracking data with google tag manager through rest api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I am new to google tag manager.I am having a google analytics account.
I integrated google analytics account with google tag manager and applied some tracking event to my google analytics account.

Is it possible to retrieve the gtm event tracking data(through rest api) through google analytics query explorer?

If it possible kindly explain the steps.

Answer (score 1):

There is really noch such thing as GTM event tracking data. You may deploy Google Analytics via GTM, but GTM itself does not collect data.

So Google Analytics event data collected by GA deployed via GTM is still just GA data, and you use the same APIs and tools (including the Query Explorer) that you would use to access GA data from properties that are not tagged using GTM.

You can however not use the GTM API to retrieve tracking data (it is not obvious from your question if you are aware of the difference).

Comment: Thank you. 
I am having a button named as Buy shirts and i set click event tracking for that button through google tag manager.
I want to retrieve data through rest api with number of  users clicking that button, their state, their country, their city,their sessions etc.
How can i get the data related to that button through query explorer?

Comment: @Krish did you found a solution to this?